# Q_ENUM external header

Tags: qt, qml

I will have a rather large amounts of enums to be used in Qt c++ frontend, QML and also in c++ backend with no Qt libraries.

I am presenting two ways to do this, both works runtime. The funny thing is moc file generated for both solutions are identical. What is the QML engine use to lookup its QT_ENUMs if the MOC files alone aren't sufficient?

Therefore i make a header file with those enums defined and include the file "inline" to make sure it is part of the class. This works, but autocomplete in QML is missing (need to alt-tab back and forward and loose efficiency)

```
#include <QObject>

class ButtonEnums : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ButtonEnums(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    #include "backend/app/messages_frontend.h"
    Q_ENUM(EnTaskSelection)
};
```

Now i have to remember copy paste and get a larger header file then desired if i do this, but autocomplete in QML works:

```
#include <QObject>

class ButtonEnums : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ButtonEnums(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    enum EnTaskSelection {
        TASK_ONE = 0, //Strict indexes defined by main menu
        TASK_TWO,
        TASK_THREE,
        TASK_FOUR
    };
    Q_ENUM(EnTaskSelection)
};
```

Comment: I am sorry, I can't find your question, or if it is "What is the QML engine use to lookup its QT_ENUMs if the MOC files alone aren't sufficient?" how it is linked to the code you have posted. Could you clear my up?

Comment: The MOC generated files are identical (as expected) in both approaches. However with the first approach (the intended one), the autocomplete is not working in QML. Question or solution could be to explain how to achieve the desired results. Or explain what other generated files I should look into to get closer to a solution